# validate readline input (CLI) inside for loop

Tags: php, console.readline

Input validation above loop works just fine, but not working in loop.
Input should not allow: string and negative numbers. Any workaround to do this or just using inside loop is not a go?
Yes, I know the maximum entered number can be checked in other ways, but I'm interested in this particular case with "for loop".

```
$amount = readline("Enter amount of inputs: ");
if (!is_numeric($amount) || !(0 < $amount)){
    echo "Invalid input";
    exit;
}
$numbers = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++){
    $numbers[] = readline("Input number {$i}: ");
    if (!is_numeric($amount) || !(0 < $amount)){
        echo "Invalid input";
        exit;
    }
}

$largestNumbers = max($numbers);
$numbersList = implode(",", $numbers);

echo "The largest number of $numbersList is $largestNumbers";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you checking `$amount` in the loop, you are reading into `$numbers`?  And since you're reading into an array you'll need to specify the index:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++){
    $numbers[$i] = readline("Input number {$i}: ");
    if (!is_numeric($numbers[$i]) || !(0 < $numbers[$i])){
        echo "Invalid input";
        exit;
    }
}
```

I might use `($numbers[$i] <= 0)` instead.

Comment: Ah sorry, that `$amount` was copy paste error before posting, but the `[i]` is good one, thnx